# how to make html5 canvas background pattern responsive

Tags: canvas, background, responsive

I have a chart made with chart.js...I want to make a background image for my canvas responsive...I made something about that...you can see with [this](http://www.360kreatif.com/ersen/efektler/bakbi.asp) link...

Bu I cannot make this background image responsive (or fit to canvas width and height)...anyone can help me?

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://www.360kreatif.com/ersen/efektler/images/light.png';
var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var fillPattern = context.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
context.fillStyle = fillPattern;
context.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

var myChart = new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            displacements: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
            backgroundColor: fillPattern,
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,0)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            cutoutPercentage:5
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                },
                tooltips: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                title: {
                    display: false,
                },
                animation: {
                    animateScale: true,
                    animateRotate: true
                }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Canvas tag is pixel based, so by definition it isnt responsive - if you need a responsive image you should try using the SVG tag, which uses vector graphics (which are responsive).